# how to config NumberRangeFilter properties (Google Visualization)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-visualization

I am newbie to Google Visualization and JS. I managed to write the following code to develop a Time Interval Data Visualization tool. But I want few more modification in existing code, therefore seeking some help over here.

Sharing the code below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        google.charts.load('current', {
            callback: drawVisualization,
            packages:['controls', 'table', 'timeline']
        });

        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

        function drawVisualization() {
            var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
            document.getElementById('dashboard'));

            var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
                'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
                'containerId': 'control',
                'options': {
                    'hAxis':{'slantedText':'true','direction':'1','format': { 'pattern':'0' }},
                    'hAxis.gridlines.color':'#ccc',
                    'hAxis': {
                        gridlines: {
                            color: 'transparent'
                        }
                    },
                    'filterColumnLabel': 'Start',
                    'ui': {
                        'format': {
                            'pattern': 0
                        },
                        'labelStacking': 'horizontal'
                    }
                }
            });

            var stringControl = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
                'controlType': 'StringFilter',
                'containerId': 'stringControl',
                'options': {
                    'hAxis':{'slantedText':'true','direction':'1','format': { 'pattern':'0' }},
                    'hAxis.gridlines.color':'#ccc',
                    'hAxis': {
                        gridlines: {
                            color: 'transparent'
                        }
                    },
                    'filterColumnLabel': 'P',
                    'matchType': 'any',
                    'ui': {
                        'format': {
                            'pattern': 0
                        },
                        'labelStacking': 'horizontal'
                    }
                }
            });

            var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
                chartType: 'Timeline',
                containerId: 'chart',
                options: {
                    'width': 1200,
                    'height': 600,
                    'timeline': {
                        'rowLabelStyle': {
                            'fontName': 'Helvetica',
                            'fontSize': 16,
                            'color': '#603913',
                        },
                        'barLabelStyle': {
                            'fontName': 'Garamond',
                            'fontSize': 9
                        }
                    },
                    'labelStacking': 'horizontal', 'format': { 'pattern':'####','fractionDigits':'0','groupingSymbol':'','showRangeValues':true },
                    backgroundColor: '#ffd',
                    hAxis: {
                        minValue: 0,
                    },
                    'chartArea': {
                        width: '100%', // make sure this is the same for the chart and control so the axes align right
                        height: '100%'
                    },
                },
                'view': {
                        'columns': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
                },
            });

            var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
                chartType: 'Table',
                containerId: 'table'
            });

            var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
// ###### Data Should be placed here ######
                ['P', 'Task', 'Msg', 'Start', 'End'],
                ['Type1'                , 'Type1_data'               , ''                                                                                             ,1      ,2],
                ['P2_1'          , 'Check_2_data'           , 'my_index 0 new_index 0'                                                                       ,101    ,102],
                ['P2_1'          , 'Check_4_data'               , 'my_index 0 new_index 0  asdjam  adasd'                                                        ,102    ,107],
                ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 1024'                                                                             ,103    ,104],
                ['Type_2'                 , ''                     , 'p 2 g 1 my_index 0 new_index 0 complete'                                        ,105    ,106],
                ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 4'                                                                                ,11     ,12],
                ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 4'                                                                                ,111    ,113],
                ['Type1'                , 'Type1_data'               , ''                                                                                             ,114    ,125],
                ['P3_0'          , 'Check_2_data'           , 'my_index 0 new_index 0  asdhas  asdhasd'                                                      ,116    ,117],
                ['P3_0'          , 'Check_4_data'               , 'my_index 0 new_index 0'                                                                       ,117    ,122],
                ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 1024'                                                                             ,118    ,119],
                ['Type_2'                 , ''                     , 'p 3 g 0 my_index 0 new_index 0 complete'                                        ,120    ,121],
                ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 4'                                                                                ,126    ,128],
                ['Type1'                , 'Type1_data'               , ''                                                                                             ,129    ,140],
                ['Type1'                , 'Type1_data'               , ''                                                                                             ,13     ,14],
                ['P4_0'          , 'Check_2_data'           , 'my_index 0 new_index 0'                                                                       ,131    ,132],
                ['P4_0'          , 'Check_4_data'               , 'my_index 0 new_index 0'                                                                       ,132    ,137],
                ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 1024'                                                                             ,133    ,134],
                ['Type_2'                 , ''                     , 'p 4 g 0 my_index 0 new_index 0 complete'                                        ,135    ,136],
                ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 4'                                                                                ,15     ,17],
                ['Type1'                , 'Type1_data'               , ''                                                                                             ,18     ,20],
                ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 4'                                                                                ,21     ,22],
                ['Type1'                , 'Type1_data'               , ''                                                                                             ,23     ,24],
                ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 4'                                                                                ,25     ,27],
                ['Type1'                , 'Type1_data'               , ''                                                                                             ,28     ,29],
                ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 4'                                                                                ,3      ,4],
                ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 4'                                                                                ,30     ,31],
                ['Type1'                , 'Type1_data'               , ''                                                                                             ,32     ,34],
                ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 4'                                                                                ,35     ,36],
                ['Type1'                , 'Type1_data'               , ''                                                                                             ,37     ,38],
                ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 4'                                                                                ,39     ,41],
                ['Type1'                , 'Type1_data'               , ''                                                                                             ,42     ,43],
                ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 4'                                                                                ,44     ,45],
                ['Type1'                , 'Type1_data'               , ''                                                                                             ,46     ,48],
                ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 4'                                                                                ,49     ,51],
                ['Type1'                , 'Type1_data'               , ''                                                                                             ,5      ,6],
                ['Type1'                , 'Type1_data'               , ''                                                                                             ,52     ,54],
                ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 4'                                                                                ,55     ,57],
                ['Type1'                , 'Type1_data'               , ''                                                                                             ,58     ,69],
                ['P0_0'          , 'Check_2_data'           , 'my_index 0 new_index 0'                                                                       ,60     ,61],
                ['P0_0'          , 'Check_4_data'               , 'my_index 0 new_index 0'                                                                       ,61     ,66],
                ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 1024'                                                                             ,62     ,63],
                ['Type_2'                 , ''                     , 'p 0 g 0 my_index 0 new_index 0 complete'                                        ,64     ,65],
                ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 4'                                                                                ,7      ,8],
                ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 4'                                                                                ,70     ,72],
                ['Type1'                , 'Type1_data'               , ''                                                                                             ,73     ,95],
                ['P1_0'          , 'Check_2_data'           , 'my_index 0 new_index 0'                                                                       ,76     ,79],
                ['P2_0'          , 'Check_2_data'           , 'my_index 1 new_index 0'                                                                       ,77     ,78],
                ['P2_0'          , 'Check_4_data'               , 'my_index 1 new_index 0'                                                                       ,78     ,91],
                ['P1_0'          , 'Check_4_data'               , 'my_index 0 new_index 0'                                                                       ,79     ,88],
                ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 1024'                                                                             ,80     ,81],
                ['Type_2'                 , ''                     , 'p 1 g 0 my_index 0 new_index 0 wt_done'                                              ,82     ,83],
                ['Type_2'                 , ''                     , 'p 1 g 0 my_index 0 new_index 0 wt_done'                                              ,84     ,85],
                ['Type_2'                 , ''                     , 'p 1 g 0 my_index 0 new_index 0 complete'                                        ,86     ,87],
                ['Type_2'                 , ''                     , 'p 2 g 0 my_index 1 new_index 0 complete'                                        ,89     ,90],
                ['Type1'                , 'Type1_data'               , ''                                                                                             ,9      ,10],
                ['Type1'                , 'Check_3_data'            , 'intr_status 4'                                                                                ,96     ,98],
                ['Type1'                , 'Type1_data'               , ''                                                                                             ,99     ,110],
// ###### End of data ######
            ]);

            data.setColumnProperty(2, 'role', 'tooltip');
            data.setColumnProperty(2, 'html', true);

// ###### Bind Table ######
            dashboard.bind([control, stringControl], [chart]);
// ###### Bind Table End here ######

            dashboard.draw(data);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<style>
    .center {
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid green;
    }
</style>

<body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
   <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

    <div id="dashboard" style="width:100%; height:100%; overflow:scroll;">

        <div class="center" id="control" style="margin-right: auto; border: 1px solid green;"> </div > <br>
        <div class="center" id="stringControl" style="margin-right: auto; border: 1px solid green;"> </div > <br> <br>
        <div id="chart" style="position: relative; width: 600px; height: 200px; bottom: 0px; padding-bottom: 200px; "></div>
        <div id="table"></div>

    </div>
</body>
```

I want to fix the following.

1. **Text overflows over the time interval events**, how to adjust it dynamically means when text can't fit in rectangular box only prefix (which can be fit in shown rectangle) should appear. And when we zoom-in the data text expand automatically within the box.

Example to demonstrate how text overflows out of the box.

[image]

Example to demonstrate how text fits in once box size increases on scrolling the `Start`.

[image]

2. **Fix the Color of Events:**: When we zoom-in the color of boxes change, how to fix it ? So that it won't change on scrolling the NumberRangeFilter  (`Start`)

Example to demonstrate how color changes automatically when we scroll the `Start` NumberRangeFilter

[image]

Please provide inputs how to do it ?

Comment: for clarification, you want a prefix in the box, if the full word can't fit?

Comment: @WhiteHat Thanks for your interest to help me out here! :)
Not Exactly, I want that  text should not overflow the box. If text size is too long to fit in default appearance of boxes, it should only display prefix if possible. What I exactly want is that, as we zoom -in and boxes size increase, text within box should expand within limits of box shape.

Comment: @WhiteHat can you please reply if I have cleared your doubt in above comment. ?

Comment: for the most part -- it's fairly straightforward to find the labels and their width, as well as the bars -- but changing to a prefix and resizing sounds trivial -- how do you determine the prefix for each label? or just cutoff what won't fit?